# "this" key word is undefined while calling static method inside another static method (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm exporting/importing an empty array to implement MVC patern and I was able to successfully store data in it by calling the **allMentors** method on the **Mentor** class.

Secondly, I want to be DRY and get the data from the array and then use it to find a specific mentor but I'm getting an empty array.

I searched the internet and I followed the example of using this keyword and call the static method inside another but NodeJS is throwing an error that this is undefined.

**ALL MENTORS method**

```
class Mentor{

static async allMentors(req, res) {

        try {

        users.forEach(user => {
            if(user.is_mentor === true) {
                mentors.push(user);
            }
        })

        const ObjKeyRename = (src, map) => {
                const dst = {};

                for (const key in src) {
                    if (key in map)
                        // rename key
                        dst[map[key]] = src[key];
                    else
                        // same key
                        dst[key] = src[key];
                }
                return dst;
        };

        const uniqueMentors = Array.from(new Set(mentors.map(m => m.id)))
                .map(id => {
                   return  new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
                        const currMentor =  mentors.find(m => m.id === id);
                        const modMentor =  ObjKeyRename(currMentor, { "id": "mentorId" });
                        return resolve(modMentor);
                    })
                }) 

        Promise.all(uniqueMentors).then(output => {
            output.forEach(async obj => {
               await delete obj['password'];
            })

            return res
            .status(200)
            .json(new ResponseHandler(200, 'All Mentors', output, null).result());
        })

        } catch (err) {
            return res
                .status(500)
                .json(new ResponseHandler(500, err.message, null).result());

        }

    }


static async singleMentor(req, res) {

        const returnedMentors = this.allMentors; 
        console.log('THE RETURNED:',returnedMentors)
        const theMentor = returnedMentors.find(u => u.mentorId === parseInt(req.params.mentorId));

        try {
            if (!theMentor) return res
                .status(404)
                .json(new ResponseHandler(404, `Mentor number ${req.params.mentorId} not found`, null).result());

            return res
                .status(200)
                .json(new ResponseHandler(200, 'Your mentor', theMentor, null).result());

        } catch (err) {
            return res
                .status(500)
                .json(new ResponseHandler(500, err.message, null).result())
        }

    }
}

export default Mentor;
```

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your continued help as a JS learner.

Comment: Why you have one static method in second?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- a static method needs to be called by Class (`Mentor`) not by Reference (`this`)
- a async method needs to be awaited or called with a callback (`.then()`)

So for example you have the class `MentorHandler`:

```
class Mentor {
  constructor() {
  }

  static async singleMentor(req, res) {

    // ... some more code
  }

  static async allMentors(req, res) {
    // await the result of the method
    // call by class
    const returnedMentors = await Mentor.allMentors(); 


    // ... some more code
  }
}
```

Comment: my static method is actually in a class; I just wanted to display a the methods. So, you mean that singleMentor method needs to come first? Let me show the whole class for more clarity.

Comment: Did you read the whole answer? You need to change your `allMentors` method to match mine, like described. @Mo1